# how to wait with setTimeout until a variable get loaded and, at the same time, receive HTTP requests!

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I' ve made a in JavaScript function to check every 100 ms if a global variable is loaded.
When the variable will be loaded the function will return the value of the
variable as shown below. In my code I use an HTTP server in JavaScript,
and the variable will be loaded when a specific HTTP request with specific
headers arrive to my server.

```
function checkVariable()
{
    if ( myvar != null )
    {
            return myVar;
    }
    else
    {
            window.setTimeout("checkVariable();",100);
    }
}
```

I use this function in a piece of code like this:

```
// arithmetis operations... [1]

myVar = checkVariable();

// arithmetic operations that use myVar [2]
```

myVar is initiated with null. The problem is that the arithmetic operations in [2] are done before myVar got its value. Instead, I want my code to wait until myVar get
its value, and then to continue with the operations.

Before trying the setTimeout function, I tried to make the code waiting using a while loop, but the problem then was that the HTTP server couldn't receive any HTTP request due to the continuously execution of the while loop!

Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would probably make the remaining arithmetric operations a callback. Something like:

```
function checkVariable()
{
    if ( myvar != null )
    {
            computeVariable(myVar);
    }
    else
    {
            window.setTimeout("checkVariable();",100);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
// arithmetis operations... [1]

myVar = checkVariable();

function computeVariable(myVar) {
  // arithmetic operations that use myVar [2]
}
```

Comment: Thank you jpoz! It's a good idea! I 'll try it! Although I would prefer a solution that doesn't use callbacks, because after the computations I would like to repeat the whole process for multiple times. That is, to make the myVar null again and to check weather some other value is loaded to it, so as to perform other operations..

Comment: Also best to avoid using a string for the method name as this ends up doing some nasty eval() code.