# Wait in a promise chain for a mutation in a DOM element

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, phantomjs, mutation-observers

I'm making some sort of web scraper in Node.js, that takes a picture of a map that appears on a website with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

However, once the page has been opened, a *loading* message appears where the map should be. Once the map is ready, the message disappears (`visibility: hidden`) and the map is shown.

Because of this, I can't call `page.render()` until `#loader` is `hidden` (or I would get a picture of the loading message, not cool).

```
// ... Open the page

.then(function(content) {
  return page.evaluate(function() {
    // Wait for #loading to get hidden somehow ...
    var clipRect = document.getElementById('map').getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      top: clipRect.top,
      left: clipRect.left,
      width: clipRect.width,
      height: clipRect.height
    };
  });
})

// Render and process the picture ...
```

I considered using a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but couldn't find a way to use it, since I'm in a **promise chain** and an event listener wouldn't work as I want.

I also tried checking for the `visibility` attribute very often until it became hidden, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224125), but PhantomJS reported through Node's console:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'child.transform')
```

Besides, I'd like to avoid that kind of workarounds if possible, because they're very CPU-intensive.

Any ideas on how can I wait for `#loader` to get `hidden` under these circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this thanks to [`phantomjs-node`](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node)'s mantainer, [amir20](https://github.com/amir20), so all credit to him. As he explains in [this issue](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/issues/431):

> `waitFor` expects to return a value. But `evaluate` returns a `Promise`. So that's why it is not working. This is not a problem of the module but rather problem with `waitFor`. Since everything is executed asynchronously then you have to wait for the value.

The function in question (created by him) is the following:

```
function waitUntil(asyncTest) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        function wait() {
            asyncTest().then(function(value) {
                if (value === true) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    setTimeout(wait, 100);
                }
            }).catch(function(e) {
                console.log('Error found. Rejecting.', e);
                reject();
            });
        }
        wait();
    });
}
```

Therefore, applied to my specific example, it should be used like this:

```
waitUtil(function() {
    return sitepage.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelectorAll('#loader').style.visibility == "hidden";
    })
}).then(function(){  // #loading is now hidden
    return page.evaluate(function() {
        var clipRect = document.getElementById('map').getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            top: clipRect.top,
            left: clipRect.left,
            width: clipRect.width,
            height: clipRect.height
        };
    });
})

// Render and process the picture ...
```